# Use AJAX to Validate email via servlet and then display overlay

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, overlay

I'm planning to use AJAX to trigger a java servlet method which checks whether an email is already in our system or not. Then when this has completed, if the email is not in our system it will dsiplay an overlay to allow the user to accept the T&Cs, if it is already in the system it will prompt them otherwise.
Being new to AJAX and that though I am confused as to how this done/fail/always stuff works. How can I trigger this emailvalidation method, and how do I then define whether it was successful or not?

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to the following code to validate email using AJAX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">                                                          
function emailCheck(){
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "email="+email;
xmlhttp.open("POST","emailcheck.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     if(xmlhttp.responseText == '0'){
         document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Email already exists.';
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Email valid.';
     document.getElementById('tnc').style.display='block';
     }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" onblur="emailCheck()" required><div id="msg"></div>
<br>
<div id="tnc" style="display: none;">
<!-- T&C here -->
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `onblur` event will call `emailCheck()` function, which contains the AJAX code to perform the required task. Also note that the email is being sent using POST method.
Your emailcheck.jsp should simply output(or print) `0` if the email already exists.